# how to write extended GCC inline assembly in Netbeans 7.4?

Tags: c

I tried to write a sample GCC extended inline assembly program in Netbeans 7.4.

the compiler options are

```
gcc -masm=intel -O2 -c -g -O2 -std=c89 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.c
```

Error shown is

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:  
main.c:27:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token  
               : [out]"=r"( op )  
               ^
```

But the code compiled successfully without some of the options. I use Cygwin (x86-x64) GCC tool-chain.

The code is

```
int main()
{
    unsigned *data = calloc ( 4 , sizeof (int ) );
    unsigned sel , op;
    scanf ( "%u%u%u%u" , data , data + 1 , data + 2 , data + 3 );
    while ( scanf ( "%u" , &sel ) )
    {
        asm(  "mov rcx, %[sel];"\
              "and rcx, 3;"\
              "mov rbx, %[data];"\
              "mov %[out], [rbx+4*rcx]"
              : [out]"=r"( op )
              : [data]"p"( data ) , [sel]"r"( sel )
              : "rcx" , "rbx"
              );
    }
    printf ( "%u\n" , op );
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: "But the code seems to be perfect." I hate it when that happens.

Comment: Somehow, it looks to me like you should edit your question